# Machine learning application to column mapping

Tags: python, machine-learning, training-data, predict

I have a dataframe with a large number of rows (several hundred thousand) and several columns that show industry classification for a company, while the eighth column is the output and shows the company type, e.g. Corporate or Bank or Asset Manager or Government etc. 
Unfortunately industry classification is not consistent 100% of the time and is not finite, i.e. there are too many permutations of the industry classification columns to be mapped once manually. If I mapped say 1k rows with correct Output columns, how can I employ machine learning with python to predict the Output column based on my trained sample data? Please see the image attached which will make it clearer.

[Part of the dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbdYd.png)

Comment: You can treat this as a multi-class classification problem. Your output column is the target. See here : https://www.kaggle.com/residentmario/notes-on-multiclass-and-multitask-schemes

Comment: Asking questions like "How do I do this?" are too vague for Stack Overflow.  If you've made a coding attempt and it's not working, we could help you with that.

Comment: @avvinci, thanks a lot for your advice!

Comment: @DanielWalker I agree, it was too vague, however, I was not asking to submit a code, but rather point me in the right direction so that I could start exploring. Thanks for feedback

Comment: Fair enough.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to predict to company type based in a couple of columns?  That is not possible, there are a lot of companies working on that. The best you can do is to collect a lot of data from different sources match them, and then you can try with `sklearn` probably a decision tree classifier to start.